# Foundation5 Off-canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I have a web application using Zurb Foundation5.3.3 and would like to intergrate the off-canvas functionality.

For some reason I can't get it to work, nothing happens when the activation link is clicked

Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/v1880qb7/1/

My off canvas code is here:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">

        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle" href="#" >Calendar</a>

        <!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
            <!-- whatever you want goes here -->

            <p> This is test content.</p>
            <div id="flat_calendar1"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar2"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar3"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar4"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar5"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar6"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar7"></div>
            <div id="flat_calendar8"></div>

        </aside>

        <!-- close the off-canvas menu -->
        <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of bad external resources. You need the file `foundation.min.js` ([link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/js/foundation.min.js)) or both of files `foundation.js` ([link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/js/foundation/foundation.js)) and `foundation.offcanvas.js` ([link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js)).

From the ZURB Foundation [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html):

> Then either load each plugin individually, or include
>   `foundation.min.js`, which automatically loads the Foundation Core and
>   all JavaScript plugins.
>
> HTML
>
> ```
> <script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
>
> <!-- or individually -->
>
> <script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
> <script src="/js/foundation.alert.js"></script>
> <!-- ... -->
> <script src="/js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
> <script src="/js/foundation.tab.js"></script>
> ```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q625j8qt/)